# heatmap without ordering and dendrogram

Tags: r, heatmap

I have a file with 2 columns and 1 million lines!! I only want to plot them without any ordering because I ordered the data.   How can I make a heatmap with heatmap.2 without any dendrogram and reordering?

when I use

```
heatmap.2(x, dendrogram="none")

Error: cannot allocate vector of size 4660.6 Gb
```

but

I tried without `"Rowv"`

```
heatmap.2(x, Rowv=FALSE) 

Warning message:
In heatmap.2(x, Rowv = FALSE) :
  Discrepancy: Rowv is FALSE, while dendrogram is `column'. Omitting row dendogram.
```

Comment: You don't offer many details, but perhaps function `heatmap1` in package `NeatMap` may be what you are after.  Or maybe `image` which is part of the basic installation.  These can create a plain heatmap.

Comment: I think heatmap.2 wraps `image`.

Comment: where does `heatmap.2` come from?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you have got both arguments there, you just have to put them together.

```
# Generate some sample data.
n<-1e6*2
m<-matrix(rnorm(n),ncol=2)
# Plot heatmap without reordering or dendrogram.
heatmap.2(m,dendrogram='none', Rowv=FALSE, Colv=FALSE,trace='none')
```

[image]

It is hard to imagine when it would be useful to plot so much data like this, but perhaps you have something in mind.